# UIView Not updating UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

In my application, a delegate callback function is called from another class. This delegate function is to repaint the screen.
like,

```
-(void)repaint {
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I have even removed the subview from UIView and then added the subView again. But still the problem persists.

My UIView is not updating.

I have NSLog the label.text and the text is updated. but screen view is not updating.

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe, you just change text in another label? ; )

Comment: Check the color of the text and alpha.

Comment: Are you sure you hooked up the label in Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes... I have hooked up the label in IB also.

I have tried all the options.

Comment: Still the same problem. UIView is not updating labels. Aplha, color everything is fine at their places.

nop.. iam changing text in the same label.

i have also NSLog(label.text);

and the updated text show on Console. but not on screen.



guysss .. help me.....

Comment: Are you positive that repaint is being called?

Comment: How is your `drawRect` defined?

Comment: Is the label showing up in your view all?  Setting the label.text will force it to refresh automatically, no need to manually refresh the view.

Answer (score 0):

An idea and a suggestion. If you properly change the text then you do not need to tell your view setNeedsDisplay - the label will have told it to. (That call is normally done when you have code in drawRect: that you need executed.)

1) When the label is changed, is it done on the main thread? Is the callback on the main thread? Add an assert to your code anywhere that label is checked:

```
NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"Yikes! Not on main thread");
NSAssert(label, @"Yikes! No label");
```

2) In the delegate above, try changing a bunch of things relating to that label

```
label.text = @"Hello World";
label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```